# Is it OK to access one database from two different application endpoints?

Tags: php, database, react-native, web, mobile

I already have a web app that uses raw PHP to access a database. Now I want to create a mobile app using react-native, that will be a mobile version of the web app, thus use the same database. What is the best way to implement the mobile app?

Comment: You can write web services in php for access database.

Comment: Probably setting up some api endpoint from your webapp. Are you using any php framework?

Comment: The best way (for me) is to separate Back End and Front end, and use same backend for the two app.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. @Andrea, the webapp was written using raw php.

Comment: @Leo R., Which is the best API to integrate with existing raw php code? Can I use GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Rest API both for your web app and mobile app. So they can share same logic as backend.

Comment: I've read that GraphQL is better than REST APIs. Can I use that instead and have PHP as the logic and GraphQL as the API?

Comment: I have not enough knowledge about php but I think it should be possible. There is php server library for graphql. Chech this;

http://graphql.org/code/